# How to make HashMap work properly with custom key type?

Tags: java, types, hashmap, key

I think my question is quite simple, however I couldn't find the solution so I decided to ask here. What i need is to make a `HashMap` with a custom Key type like this:

```
HashMap<Pair<Integer, Integer>, StrategyPoint> myMap = new HashMap<Pair<Integer, Integer>, StrategyPoint> ();
```

However I am missing something here, because the `HashMap` stops working properly. First the Key becomes not unique and a different instances of Pair with same values can be found in the `keySet`. Also the contains key function does not work the way I suppose it to :).

I clearly miss something and more likely I should somehow define a way to compare my instances from my `Pair` class. However I tried implementing Comparable with `compareTo` in my `Pair` class and it still don't work. Any suggestions?

My original code is kinda messy and unfriendly to read, so I made an example just to illustrate my problem here.

Here is the code:

```
HashMap<Pair<Integer, Integer>, StrategyPoint> myMap = new HashMap<Pair<Integer, Integer>, StrategyPoint> ();
    Pair<Integer, Integer> myPair = new Pair<Integer, Integer>(2,2);
    StrategyPoint myPoint= new StrategyPoint(2, 2, 5, 5, false);
    myMap.put(myPair, myPoint);


    Pair<Integer, Integer> searcher = new Pair<Integer, Integer> (0,0);
    searcher.setFirst(2);
    searcher.setSecond(2);
    System.out.println(myMap.containsKey(searcher));
    System.out.println(myMap.containsKey(myPair));
```

The result from execution is:

```
false

true
```

I have debug it and the searcher instance is being populated properly, however it seems the `HashMap` refuse to find it in its `keySet`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You must implement properly `equals` and `hashCode` on the `Pair` class.

The `HashMap` uses these methods to differentiate and hash the key class.

Answer (score 7):

You need to override `equals` in the class `Pair`. The implementation of this method defines how two objects of `Pair` are considered equal.

And whenever you override `equals` you must always override `hashcode`.

Here is what can go wrong when you override `equals` but not `hashcode` (from Effective Java, Second Ed.):

> Two distinct instances may be logically equal according to a class’s
>   equals method, but to Object’s hashCode method, they’re just two
>   objects with nothing much in common. Therefore Object’s hashCode
>   method returns two seemingly random numbers instead of two equal
>   numbers as required by the contract.

Because the hashcodes for two logically equal instances become unequal, if you try to search for one while another is in the collection, you will end up looking in the wrong hash bucket which results in `null`.

There is a set of [rules](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) that implementation of `equals` must conform to. Another set of [rules](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) for overriding `hashcode`.

Comment: -1: Your answer is late, and incomplete. The two other ones are correct already.

Comment: At the time of the downvote, you completely forgot about hashCode, which made your answer plain wrong (and thus not useful). Don't try to rewrite history. I removed my downvote, since the answer is now fixed.

Comment: aye aye, sir - I hear the command, I understand it and will comply with the order :)

Answer (score 3):

Your Pair class need to implement `hashCode()` and `equals()` according to the contract specified in the Javadoc for `Object`.